# My node server is not able to recognize the es6 syntax even with the babel library loaded

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am having a lot of trouble rendering my react/redux app on my server. First I am requiring all the necessary babel libraries so the node server can recognize the syntax when reading the jsx files, but I still get syntax errors. The error I get is `> 8 | return { ...state, check: true }; Unexpected token pointing at the ...`

server.js

```
require('babel-register')({ presets: ['es2015', 'react'] });
require('import-export');
require('babel-polyfill');

const reducers = require('../src/reducers').default; //written with es6 import statements and export default
```

reducers

```
export default function(state = INITIAL, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "CHECK":
      return { ...state, check: true }; //error reading this line
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{...obj}` syntax is an ES7 feature named `object-rest-spread` under babel, so the 2015/react presets don't include it. You'll have to add it to your babel config like `"plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]`

More info [on the babel site](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: Wouldn't I have to add to my presets in the require('babel-register')?

Comment: It would be alongside your presets

`require('babel-register')({ presets: ['es2015', 'react'] , plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']});`

Comment: it's not the rest spread, it's a normal spread, which is part of es2015 preset https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-spread/